# TokenMismatchException with facebook App using Laravel5

Tags: facebook, laravel

Facebook application with Laravel5.4 works fine in url but when i try to open it in Facebook fan page,i get

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68

though i am not posting any form here,its just a get request which load the home view.

How can i fix this ?

Here is my code. [View code](https://kopy.io/1iNvo)

Comment: Can you please post your code, so that we can go through it and help you!

Comment: Have you `form` in `home` page? Also, if this error occurs when submitting a form then you must need to add `token` field within that form. Because you already mentioned that you got this error after submitting a form!

Comment: I have a form,but on first request it is not submitting,any btw i have crsr_field enabled in form as well as in header,but nothing works

Comment: Post the code where you submitting a form please.

Comment: Please have a look at this https://kopy.io/qhKSc

Comment: Facebook loads your app into the iframe via a POST request - they create the form on their end, and then automatically submit it via JavaScript. You need to disable the CRSF protection in your settings.

Comment: @CBroe: thank you for useful information,do i need to disable it from Laravel code,or these is any option at Facebook end as well ?

Comment: I think you can disable it from the middleware settings! Please refer this for such help: http://www.camroncade.com/disable-csrf-for-specific-routes-laravel-5/

Comment: Thank you for help and suggestions @HirenGohel

Comment: No problem, let me know when you fixed it!

Comment: I have fixed it,again thank you

Comment: OK great! Your welcome brother! Plz post your solution so that someone get the solution from here! Or can i post answer so that you can accept and upvote as well?

Comment: You can call me sis :)

Comment: I just disabled the \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, from kernel.php

Comment: Sure post it,and i will upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment out this line in `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

You can also disable for specific routes like:

```
protected $except = [
    'user/*',
];
```

Or you can disable it on route file. For example:

```
Route::post('user/{id}/update', [
    'uses' => 'UserController@update',
    'nocsrf' => true,
]);
```